# BufferedReader , readLine operates at half

Tags: java, android, tcp, client-server

Hello i try to read a number undetermined of lines(between 1 and 150, each lines is vontaines in a packet, and a packet contains 1 number and 1 text) with my java app(when the connexion between the client ans the server is established) but it seems its work at half. I receive only between 2 and 3 lines, can somebody can help me ?

```
class test implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

                while(true){
                    DataInputStream reader = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            int tailleMessage = reader.readUnsignedShort();
            if (reader.available() < tailleMessage ){
                return;
            }
               while (( messagep = inFromClient.readLine()) != null){
                   tailleMessage = reader.readUnsignedShort();
               final String azrty = messagep;                    

            if(!azrty.isEmpty()){
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Chat.TextChat.append("\n"+azrty);
                }

            });
            }

               }
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("erreur",e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use both a BufferedReader and another input stream at the same time on a Socket. The buffer will 'steal' data from the input stream. You need to redesign your protocol accordingly. Possibly you should use writeUTF()/readUTF() to send the strings, instead of sending them as lines. Or is sibyl you should be using ObjectInput/OutputStreams.

Comment: the DataInputStream is just for see if there are data available, i can't use writeUTF() because I use a C++ client with Qt and c + + does not have this method.

Comment: You are also using it for readUnsignedShort().  You don't need available(). readLine() will block while there is no data. Your protocol doesn't actually make sense as you have coded it. It seems you should be reading one integer and then that many lines. You may have to use DataInputStream.readLine(), despite the deprecation.

Comment: ok, but it seem odd to me because the client read the three first lines then i need to send another line and at this moment i will receive three other lines

Comment: It's pointless to discuss how your present implementation works, because it doesn't.

Comment: Your method works perfectly :) thank. What do you recommend me ? use a DataInputStream like you previously recommend me or use BufferedReader but change the sending line method and only send the line instead of a number + the line, the number was serving me know the length of the line

Comment: If you're sending lines, you don't need the length: the line terminator is sufficient.